# propel DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Element 'foreign-key', attribute 'ondelete','onupdate','skipsql' The attribute is not allowing?

Tags: php, orm, propel

I am using propel PHP: The foreign key attries are not getting depended on the parent table. The Creations, updates, deletes are taken place in parent is not effecting the child table.

foreign-key elements like onupdate,ondelete,skipsql is not acceping by the propel and error's like this

> DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Element 'foreign-key', attribute 'ondelete','onupdate','skipsql'

The attribute is not allowing?

Comment: Please proof read your question, it's hard to say what you ask about. What does *"The attribute is not allowing?"*  is for a question, please elaborate. Also ensure you put the **full** error message into your question.

Comment: Sorry, I made the error in short line -- so you didn't understand ?  I got the result, I found my mistake on the code.                                                                Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Please add your code and also add your solution (result) as an answer below. That should clarify the problem in your question, too. You can then select the answer.

Comment: I got answer it is syntax error in the xml file on table tag.

Comment: I have a question ?   Right now I am using Propel and PFBC(php From Builder class). I wrote the validations in xml file using propel now I want to use them when login button is clicked. It means I want to check the validation of form variables and database validation rules. Can you help me. Please?

Comment: No I can not help, I'm not fluent with Propel, sorry. After you have answered this question here, you might want to ask a new question.

Comment: I am new to this site I don't know how to post xml code can you explain the things for me

Comment: @kirankotari: your answer looks good with the code-highlight I'd say. Have you found the link to the editing help? If not, let me know.

Comment: Thank u 'j0k' I accepted it.

Comment: hakre I want to know about this site more, how it works and helps me. You know this is my first question? suggest me how to use this site more and more. please

Comment: @kirankotari more information can be found in the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, it's syntax mistake in my xml file.

```
<table name="names" phpName="Name">
<column name="nameid" phpName="Nid" type="integer" size="11" required="true" primaryKey="true"
autoIncrement="true" description="Name ID"/>
<column name="name" phpName="Name" type="varchar" size="50" required="true"
description="Name"/>
<validator column="name">
<rule name="required" message="Name is Required"/>
<rule name="minLength" value="3" message="Enter Valid Full-Name, Minimum of 3 characters"/>
<rule name="maxLength" value="20" message="Invalid Entry"/>
<rule name="match" value="/^[\w]+$/" message="No Special Character Allowed"/>
<rule name="unique" />
</validator>
</table>

<table name="relations" phpName="Relations">
<column name="rid" type="integer" size="11" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"
description="Relational ID"/>

<column name="pnid" type="integer" size="11" required="true" description="name User ID"/>

<column name="rnid" type="integer" size="11" required="true" description="name Relationship ID"/>

<column name="relation" type="varchar" size="100" required="true" description="Relationship"/>

<validator column="relation">
<rule name="required" message="Relationship Type is Required" />
<rule name="match" value="/^([\w])+([\.\w\-]+)+$/" message="Enter a Valid String" />
<rule name="minLength" value="3" message="Enter a Valid Relation Ship"/>
<rule name="maxLength" value="20" message="Invalid Entry"/>
</validator>

<foreign-key foreignTable="names" onUpdate="CASCADE" onDelete="CASCADE">
<reference local="pnid" foreign="nid" />
<reference local="rnid" foreign="nid" />
</foreign-key>
</table>
```